# My app_id, app_ secert, and app id of pusher is missing

Tags: php, pusher

I was working on the realtime comment system for my website using pusher.I have set the following setting of the pusher for my website.

```
$pusher = new Pusher(
 '**************', //APP KEY
 '*************', //APP SECRET
 '*****' //APP ID
);
```

It is working prefectly but I am getting following errors.

> Severity: Warning Message: Missing argument 1 for
>   Pusher::__construct(), called in /var/www/system/core/Loader.php on
>   line 1099 and defined Filename: libraries/Pusher.php Line Number: 72

What can be the error. Any help will be great.

Comment: what is Line Number: 72, show please

Comment: public function __construct( $auth_key, $secret, $app_id, $debug = false, $host = 'http://api.pusherapp.com', $port = '80', $timeout = 30 )

Comment: I have already send authkey, secret and app_id from above..

Comment: as per the error, you are missing to provide some arguments.

Comment: what is /var/www/system/core/Loader.php on line 1099

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using codeigniter, Need to load the library pusher in the constructor of the controller.

I have done it.